# Split Strings with Multiple Delimiters and Concat

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm, split

I'd like to print out all possible sentences from this kind of strings below. What is the best way to do it?

```
[my/your/his/her] (best/true) friend is | [who/where] is [your/her/his](best/true) friend
```

1. my best friend is
2. your best friend is
3. his best friend is
4. her best friend is
5. my true friend is
6. your true friend is
7. his true friend is
8. her true friend is
9. who is your best friend
10. who is her best friend
11. who is his best friend
12. who is your true friend
13. who is her true friend
14. who is his true friend
15. where is your best friend
16. where is her best friend
17. where is his best friend
18. where is your true friend
19. where is her true friend
20. where is his true friend

Comment: Write a bunch of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin functions for what you need. So you need to make a solution.

First of all you need to split this task into more trivial parts.

One part would accept array of arrays and perform combination on it:

```
// Converts [['a'], ['b', 'c']] to ['ab', 'ac']
const combination = (parts) => {
  let current = [[]]
  parts.forEach(v => {
    let result = []
    current.forEach(c => {
      v.forEach(n => {
        result.push(c.concat(n))
      })
    })
    current = result
  })
  return current.map(v => v.join(' '))
}
```

The other part needs to convert your input into array of arrays and format an output:

```js
const generate = (formats) => {
  let result = []

  // Converts [['a'], ['b', 'c']] to ['ab', 'ac']
  const combination = (parts) => {
    let current = [[]]
    parts.forEach(v => {
      let result = []
      current.forEach(c => {
        v.forEach(n => {
          result.push(c.concat(n))
        })
      })
      current = result
    })
    return current.map(v => v.join(' '))
  }
  formats.split('|').forEach((format) => {
    let parts = format
      .split(/[\]\[\)\(]/) // split "[a] (b) c" to ["a", "b", "c"]
      .filter(String) // remove empy elements
      .map(s => {return s.trim()})
      .filter(String) // there can be empty strings. remove those too
    parts = parts.map(part => {return part.split('/')})
    result = result.concat(combination(parts))
  })
  return result
}

let input = "[my/your/his/her] (best/true) friend is | [who/where] is [your/her/his](best/true) friend"
generate(input).forEach((v, i) => {console.log((i+1) + '. ' + v)})
```

This is pretty much you need. Though there are some corner cases that should be covered and a little problem with line `.split(/[\]\[\)\(]/)`. But I'm sure you can fix it.

Comment: Strings inside of the round brackets are optional. I also want to print out possible sentences without them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @nanokozmos you can convert `(a/b)` to `[a/b/]`.

Comment: What if some optional strings don't need extra space? For example "I [like/love] my car(s)" @teivaz

Comment: @nanokozmos then you'll need to update regexp and some change filtering.